# Open source hardware at NASA

Tags: nasa, spacecraft, rovers, spacecraft-development, open-source

Given NASA has its [open source software repository](https://code.nasa.gov/), I can not really find its [open source hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_hardware) counterpart so I suppose such a thing does not exist. Is that true?

The [3D models site](https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/models) ([GitHub mirror?](https://github.com/nasa/NASA-3D-Resources)) seems to mostly contain models of the outer structures only. Searching [NASA's GitHub](https://github.com/nasa) for hardware yields mostly hardware device drivers. [JPL's GitHub](https://github.com/nasa-jpl) is not any better.

However I guess NASA almost certainly released some open source hardware but it probably is hard to find. One recent example may be the [Open Source Rover](http://opensourcerover.jpl.nasa.gov) ([code](https://github.com/nasa-jpl/open-source-rover)) which is a special case though since that is mostly a toy only. I am looking for a real functional spaceflight hardware. So what are the most notable open source hardware projects at NASA?

By open source hardware I mean any mechanical structure (spacecraft chassis, tanks, engines, electronics etc.).

Comment: possibly related: [Why isn't SpaceX's Starship “trial and error” development strategy an **open source** project?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49789)

Comment: Hardware is often patented or developed by a contracting company, not NASA directly.  Therefore, the company will maintain proprietary control of intellectual property but they are required to disclose much of this information to the project scientist and project managers etc. of the mission during development for record keeping and compliance checks etc.